# how to enable wifi usb tp link wr725n without built-in button?

Tags: wireless, adapter, button

My button is broken and if i enable with button, that every 1-2 min will turn disable and enable, wifi.

On windows 7 i can enable wifi adapter(tp-link wr725n) without this button, how to do that on ubuntu ?

Comment: Can you remove the internal wifi card?

Comment: no, my trouble with this button, i cant enable usb adapter without button.

Comment: But you do have an internal wifi card?

Comment: yes, that a laptop.

Comment: Remove the internal wifi card and the button might not be an issue anymore

Comment: i found that "cat /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/state"  returned 2 if disable and 1 if enable how to make 1 if button disable ? i added to blacklist iwlwifi (my internal wifi card ). I dont know why ubuntu disabled my usb wifi with this button.